# How to 'unquote' when creating Expression tree from lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, f#, expression-trees

Let's suppose I have some function `c` that return `Expression`:

```
Func<int, Expression<Func<int>>> c = (int a) => () => a + 3;
```

Now I want to create another `Expression`, but during its creation I'd like to call the function `c` and embed its result as the part of new expression:

```
Expression<Func<int>> d = () => 2 + c(3);
```

I can't do this way because it will interpret `c(3)` like a functions call to be converted to expression and I'll get the error that I cant add `int` and `Expression<Func<int>>`

I'd like `d` to have a value of:

```
(Expression<Func<int>>)( () => 2 + 3 + 3 )
```

I'm also interested in getting this to work on more complex expressions, not just this toy example.

**How would you do it in C#?**

Alternatively, how would you do it in any other CLR language that I could use in my C# project with as little hassle as possible?

---

More complex examples:

```
Func<int, Expression<Func<int>>> c = (int a) => () => a*(a + 3);
Expression<Func<int, int>> d = (x) => 2 + c(3 + x);
```

`3+x` should be evaluated just once in resulting expression even though it occurs in body of `c` in two places.

---

I have a strong feeling that it cannot be achieved in C# because assigning lambda to `Expression` is done by the compiler and is sort of compile time `const` expression literal. It would be akin to making compiler that understands plain string literal `"test"` understand template string literal `"test ${a+b} other"` and C# compiler is not at this stage of development yet.

So my main question actually is:

**What CLR language supports syntax that would allow me to conveniently build Expression trees embedding parts that are constructed by other functions?**

Other possibility is some library that would help me build expression trees in this way using some sorts of run-time compiled templates but I'm guessing this way I'd loose code completion for my expression code.

---

It seems that F# has ability to 'quote' and 'unquote' (splice) the code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/code-quotations

Comment: So the end result would be `() => 2 + 3 + 3`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes. Desired result is `d` to be `(Expression<Func<int>>)( () => 2 + 3 + 3 )`

Comment: You can't convert a delegate to an expression tree.

Comment: Regarding the more complex example, wouldn't the result be `(x) => 2 + (3 + x)*(3 + x + 3)`? Here `x + 3` is evaluated twice not once.

Comment: @YacoubMassad I'd expect something like: `(x, tmp = 3+x) => 2 + tmp*(3 + tmp)` or `(x) => { var tmp = 3+x; return 2+tmp*(3+tmp) }`

Comment: Important question for a possible answer - Are you using this with ultimately LINQ to objects, or some other LINQ provider (like Entity Framework)?

Comment: You can use expressions to build other expressions by using the [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) library. You can do a similar thing manually but it involves more work. I don't think that what you ask stops at simple expressions usage in other expressions. You want to store a temp value. You can this manually by constructing a new expression from the old one. An [ExpressionVisitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx) might help here.

Comment: @jdphenix Yes. Ultimately I'd like to use it on expressions that LINQ supports. I need this to construct complex queries for Entity Framework. Technically I could construct expression trees completely manually but lambdas are so much easier to read and write.

Comment: I don't think that EF supports multi-statement expressions.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Ok. I can live with multiple evaluation, maybe some later stage of the pipeline will be able to deduplicate it.

Comment: your c method would need to be created with Expression objects from ground up if you plan to use with linq to db drivers, since delegate conversion won't work with them

Comment: @YacoubMassad With LINQ to Objects, you can create a pretty simple compose function that let's you do compose functions like `Compose(y => y + 6, x => x + 3)`; I haven't had luck (yet) with writing something that works with EF entities though.

Comment: @KamilSzot Anyhow this comment chain is really long - can you update your question with the constraints that a proposed solution must work with Entity Framework?

Comment: @jdphenix, I don't know about Compose functions. Can you provide a reference that describes them?

Comment: @jdphenix That's how I plan to use it but I don't want to specify it as constraint because I fairly sure that I'll be able to extend unconstrained solution to the one that will work for EF.

Comment: @YacoubMassad I'm speaking of a C# implementation of function composition, here's a decent post on the topic https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrsmith/2008/06/14/function-composition/

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic Not neccessarily. Function `c` constructs some `Expression.Lambda`. I can take its body and substitute parameter accesses for actual Expressions that I pass to `c`. What I really want is to be able to do it with convenient syntax.

Comment: @KamilSzot, one major problem is that `c` itself is a function (real code), not an expression (code as data). You would need to convert it to `Expression<Func<int,int>> c = (int a) => a * (a + 3);`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad This won't help me with embedding it into lambda Expression literal and it's too strong limitation for my use case.

Comment: Actually this will help you embed it. However your limitation is a different story.

Comment: @Evk There's no difference in how hard is to embed `Expression<Func<int, int>> d = (x) => 2 + <unquote(c())>` and Expression<Func<int, int>> d = (x) => 2 + <unquote(c)>` because both things are impossible. And if I'll construct manually there's no difference between `Expression<Func<int, int>> d = Expression.Lambda(... c() ..)` and `Expression<Func<int, int>> d = Expression.Lambda(... c ..)` ... besides `c` could be a property with a getter function so there's really no difference.

Comment: Thank you all for help. I think I'll write this part of my application in F# using `<@ ... %c() ...  @>` syntax and converters from F# Expr-s to Expression trees.

Comment: What I (and probably Yacoub) mean is if instead of this `Func<int, Expression<Func<int>>> c = (int a) => () => a + 3;` you had this `Expression<Func<int,int>> c = (int a) => (a + 3)` - then you can actually get your desired result (`(Expression<Func<int>>)( () => 2 + 3 + 3 )`). For example with LinqKit.

Comment: @Evk Wow LinqKit is cool. Thanks for dropping it's name here.

Comment: If you already saw my answer, you might be interested in the update to it (not sure if answer updates are notified to asker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both of your examples this can actually be done with two expression visitors (code is commented):

```
static class Extensions {
    public static TResult FakeInvoke<TResult>(this Delegate instance, params object[] parameters)
    {
        // this is not intended to be called directly
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static TExpression Unwrap<TExpression>(this TExpression exp) where TExpression : Expression {
        return (TExpression) new FakeInvokeVisitor().Visit(exp);
    }

    class FakeInvokeVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node) {
            // replace FakeInvoke call
            if (node.Method.Name == "FakeInvoke") {
                // first obtain reference to method being called (so, for c.FakeInvoke(...) that will be "c")
                var func = (Delegate)Expression.Lambda(node.Arguments[0]).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
                // explore method argument names and types
                var argumentNames = new List<string>();
                var dummyArguments = new List<object>();
                foreach (var arg in func.Method.GetParameters()) {
                    argumentNames.Add(arg.Name);
                    // create default value for each argument
                    dummyArguments.Add(arg.ParameterType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(arg.ParameterType) : null);
                }
                // now, invoke function with default arguments to obtain expression (for example, this one () => a*(a + 3)).
                // all arguments will have default value (0 in this case), but they are not literal "0" but a reference to "a" member with value 0
                var exp = (Expression) func.DynamicInvoke(dummyArguments.ToArray());
                // this is expressions representing what we passed to FakeInvoke (for example expression (x + 3))
                var argumentExpressions = (NewArrayExpression)node.Arguments[1];
                // now invoke second visitor
                exp = new InnerFakeInvokeVisitor(argumentExpressions, argumentNames.ToArray()).Visit(exp);
                return ((LambdaExpression)exp).Body;
            }
            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }
    }

    class InnerFakeInvokeVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
        private readonly NewArrayExpression _args;
        private readonly string[] _argumentNames;
        public InnerFakeInvokeVisitor(NewArrayExpression args, string[] argumentNames) {
            _args =  args;
            _argumentNames = argumentNames;
        }
        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node) {
            // if that is a reference to one of our arguments (for example, reference to "a")
            if (_argumentNames.Contains(node.Member.Name)) {
                // find related expression
                var idx = Array.IndexOf(_argumentNames, node.Member.Name);
                var argument = _args.Expressions[idx];
                var unary = argument as UnaryExpression;
                // and replace it. So "a" is replaced with expression "x + 3"
                return unary?.Operand ?? argument;
            }
            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Can be used like this:

```
Func<int, Expression<Func<int>>> c = (int a) => () => a * (a + 3);
Expression<Func<int, int>> d = (x) => 2 + c.FakeInvoke<int>(3 + x);
d = d.Unwrap(); // this is now "x => (2 + ((3 + x) * ((3 + x) + 3)))"
```

Simple case:

```
Func<int, Expression<Func<int>>> c = (int a) => () => a + 3;
Expression<Func<int>> d = () => 2 + c.FakeInvoke<int>(3);
d = d.Unwrap(); // this is now "() => 2 + (3 + 3)
```

With multiple arguments:

```
Func<int, int, Expression<Func<int>>> c = (int a, int b) => () => a * (a + 3) + b;
Expression<Func<int, int>> d = (x) => 2 + c.FakeInvoke<int>(3 + x, x + 5);
d = d.Unwrap(); // "x => (2 + (((3 + x) * ((3 + x) + 3)) + (x + 5)))"
```

Note that FakeInvoke is not type-safe (you should explicitly set return type and arguments and not checked). But that's just for example, in real use you can create many overloads of FakeInvoke, like this:

```
public static TResult FakeInvoke<TArg, TResult>(this Func<TArg, Expression<Func<TResult>>> instance, TArg argument) {
        // this is not intended to be called directly
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Code above should be modified a bit to handle such calls correctly (because arguments are now not in single NewArrayExpression), but that's quite easy to do. With such overloads you can just do:

```
Expression<Func<int, int>> d = (x) => 2 + c.FakeInvoke(3 + x); // this is type-safe now, you cannot pass non-integer as "3+x", nor you can pass more or less arguments than required.
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer made me dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

The case where Expressions are returned from lambdas is really hard because those Expressions are actually closures that have non-public (`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure`?) object inside them that contains the values that lambda closes over. All of that makes really hard to accurately replace formal parameters with actual parameters in Expression tree.

---

Inspired by [Evk response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40811627/166921) I found fairly elegant solution for simpler case:

```
Expression<Func<int, int>> c = (int a) => a * (a + 3);
var d = Extensions.Splice<Func<int, int>>((x) => 2 + c.Embed(3 + x));

// d is now x => (2 + ((3 + x) * ((3 + x) + 3))) expression
```

---

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T Embed<T>(this Expression<Func<T>> exp) { throw new Exception("Should not be executed"); }
    public static T Embed<A, T>(this Expression<Func<A, T>> exp, A a) { throw new Exception("Should not be executed"); }
    public static T Embed<A, B, T>(this Expression<Func<A, B, T>> exp, A a, B b) { throw new Exception("Should not be executed"); }
    public static T Embed<A, B, C, T>(this Expression<Func<A, B, C, T>> exp, A a, B b, C c) { throw new Exception("Should not be executed"); }
    public static T Embed<A, B, C, D, T>(this Expression<Func<A, B, C, D, T>> exp, A a, B b, C c) { throw new Exception("Should not be executed"); }

    public static Expression<T> Splice<T>(Expression<T> exp)
    {
        return new SplicingVisitor().Visit(exp) as Expression<T>;
    }
    class SplicingVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Method.Name == "Embed")
            {
                var mem = node.Arguments[0] as MemberExpression;

                var getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(mem, new ParameterExpression[0]);
                var lam = getterLambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke() as LambdaExpression;

                var parameterMapping = lam.Parameters.Select((p, index) => new
                {
                    FormalParameter = p,
                    ActualParameter = node.Arguments[index+1]
                }).ToDictionary(o => o.FormalParameter, o => o.ActualParameter);

                return new ParameterReplacerVisitor(parameterMapping).Visit(lam.Body);
            }
            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }
    }
    public class ParameterReplacerVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> parameterMapping;
        public ParameterReplacerVisitor(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> parameterMapping)
        {
            this.parameterMapping = parameterMapping;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if(parameterMapping.ContainsKey(node))
            {
                return parameterMapping[node];
            }
            return base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about your more complex case then?

Comment: @Evk I got it working but code was really messy and it could potentially replace parameters wrongly in more complex cases where there are a lot of parameters and object fields that share names. To tell them apart I'd need access to LambdaExpression internal closure object that holds the enclosed values. The only way I even saw this object was by compiling closure lambda and looking into `Target.Constants` field on it. I just decided that I'll try to manage with just static (non-closure) expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Using [LinqKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/), it simple to consume it's expandable query wrapper by calling `AsExpandable()` on the first entity type. This expandable wrapper does the work necessary to compose expressions make them compatible with EF.

A toy example of it's usage is below (`Person` is an EF Code First entity) -

```
var ctx = new Test();

Expression<Func<Person, bool>> ageFilter = p => p.Age < 30;

var filtered = ctx.People.AsExpandable()
    .Where(p => ageFilter.Invoke(p) && p.Name.StartsWith("J"));
Console.WriteLine( $"{filtered.Count()} people meet the criteria." );
```