# How can I reuse the logic in a Where call while working with Entity Framework Core in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I am writing a database query using LINQ in .NET and I want to be able to not duplicate the code I put in my `Where` method calls. All my entities inherit `BaseEntity` and have in common the properties used in the `Where` call.

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class A : BaseEntity
{
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B : BaseEntity
{
    public A A { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment I have written a query that works but I am not satisfied that I need to duplicate code. It looks like this:

```
var result = _context.Set<A>().Include(a => a.Bs.Where(b => b.DeletedAt == null && b.UpdatedAt > dateTime ||
                                                            b.DeletedAt != null && b.DeletedAt > dateTime))
                              .Where(a => a.DeletedAt == null && a.UpdatedAt > dateTime ||
                                          a.DeletedAt != null && a.DeletedAt > dateTime)
                              .ToList();
```

As you can see the code in `Where` calls is pretty much the same, yet I couldn't find a way to put it in a place and be able to reuse it. I did try to create an extension for `IQueryable` but I wouldn't be able to use it in the `Where` inside the `Include` becuause `Bs` is not `IQueryable`.
Obviously, just putting the logic in a method doesn't work because it can't be translated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390126/how-can-i-use-a-predicatet-in-an-ef-where-clause

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I can't create Expressions because in the `a.Bs.Where(...)` it actually expects a `Func`, not an `Expression`. Yet, if i just put a `Func` in a variable and then use it, it wouldn't be able to translate the query.

Comment: You are wrong. The `Where` in the `Include` works and it is also necessary. I just need a way to reuse that statement as it will appear in many places and I don't want to have to copy it all over the place.

Comment: Unfortunately the C# compiler has no notion of "expression splicing", whereby you can syntactically compose expression trees. What you can do however is factor out the innermost `Expression<Func<BaseEntity, Bool>>`, pass it unchanged in the second position, and for the first position synthesize an appropriate `Expression<Func<A, List<B>>>` using the tools described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/expression-trees-building) and the `Expression<Func<BaseEntity, Bool>>` you factored out.

Comment: You might find the information here relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810227/how-to-unquote-when-creating-expression-tree-from-lambda

Answer (score 0):

A common expression should work, it possibly wasn't implemented correctly as they can be somewhat temperamental. For instance:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> FilterByDate<T>(DateTime dateTime) where T : BaseEntity
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = x => 
        (x.DeletedAt == null && x.UpdatedAt > dateTime) 
        || (x.DeletedAt != null && x.DeletedAt > dateTime)
    return expression;
}
```

Then in your query:

```
var result = _context.Set<A>().Include(a => a.Bs.Where(filterByDate<B>(dateTime))
    .Where(a => filterByDate<A>(dateTime))
    .ToList();
```

The tests I ran with a base class for dates looked to work for both the filtering of the items and the included children. It did require explicitly providing the type to the filter call.